# Animated GIF images are slow on iOS

Tags: performance, graphics

Animated GIF images seem incredibly slow since iOS 4.3ish. Prior to that, animated GIFs worked just fine and had the same speed as on a computer. I don't mean loading the GIF, but the speed of the animation. They are the same on the iPhone 3GS and iPad 2, so it's probably not hardware based. However, they work fine in the Simulator. I suspect the libraries were changed at some point. Can anyone confirm this, and/or provide a remedy. Animated GIFs hosted at [senorgif.com](http://senorgif.com) are the main culprits.

EDIT: iOS 6 seems to have fixed the issue; probably a memory allocation related, since each frame used to get slower and slower :P

Comment: This still happens for me on iOS 6, though I think it has gotten better since I first noticed it years ago. This example is pretty bad on an iPad 2: http://i.minus.com/ibiWWOI8pdbXNC.gif

Comment: Similarly bad on 3Gs, drops below 1fps after a while.

Comment: It would seem that since it slows down anyway that it doesn't matter what device you're on - it'll just take longer to slow down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I visited the link provided, and I was unable to recreate this issue. The speed of the animations seems perfectly fine on iPhone 4S. If you have had this problem on numerous devices, I kindly suggested reporting it to Apple as a potential bug. More than likely, if it hasn't already been reported, an engineer will get back to you with a request and instructions on how to submit more information regarding the matter to them.

To submit a bug report to apple, visit http://bugreport.apple.com.

I would also like to suggest downloading Google Chrome for iOS or Opera Browser for iOS and visiting the same website(s). See if the animations are just as slow there. This will give you a bit more detail to submit to Apple with your bug report. If the issue is only in Mobile Safari, that will help them track the problem down much faster. If it exists in all browsers on the device, they will know that they need to look a bit deeper into iOS itself. Either way, I'm afraid I can't offer a quick fix for the issue as it seems to be a rather rare occurrence.

Good luck and happy LOLing!

Comment: Unfortunately, Chrome doesn't fix the issue on iOS 4/5. However, iOS 6 appears to have fixed it.